# DeviceInformation::FindAllAsync fails to find devices with RFCOMM service ID

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, rfcomm

I want a simple client/server setup with two Windows Phones, and I'm using the following code to set up the server:

```
auto providerTask = create_task(RfcommServiceProvider::CreateAsync(RfcommServiceId::FromUuid(GetServiceGUID())));

providerTask.then([this](RfcommServiceProvider^ p) -> task < void >
{
    this->provider = p;

    this->listener = ref new StreamSocketListener();
    listener->ConnectionReceived += ref new Windows::Foundation::TypedEventHandler < Windows::Networking::Sockets::StreamSocketListener ^,
        Windows::Networking::Sockets::StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs ^ >
        (this, &ConnectionManager::OnConnectionReceived);

    return create_task(listener->BindServiceNameAsync(provider->ServiceId->AsString())).then([this]()
    {
        this->provider->StartAdvertising(listener);
    });

}).then([](task<void> t)
{
    //handle exceptions at the end of the chain
    try
    {
        t.get();
    }
    catch (Platform::Exception^ ex)
    {
        if (ex->HResult == 0x9000000F)
        {
            OutputDebugString(L"Bluetooth is disabled.\n");
        }
        else throw ex;
    }
});
```

GetServiceGUID() just returns the identifier I created for my App with VS's built-in GUID tool; the same one is also declared in the app manifest.

On the second device I'm looking for servers like this:

```
auto query = RfcommDeviceService::GetDeviceSelector(RfcommServiceId::FromUuid(GetServiceGUID()));

create_task(DeviceInformation::FindAllAsync(query))
    .then([this](DeviceInformationCollection^ services)
{
    if (services->Size > 0)
    {
        OutputDebugString(L"We've found a server!\n");
        OutputDebugString(services->First()->Current->Name->Data());
    }
});
```

The call to FindAllAsync always returns an empty collection, even though both devices are shown as paired in the settings. However, if I use RfcommServiceId::ObexObjectPush instead of FromUuid when setting up the server and later when enumerating devices, it works fine. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: What do the AQS selector strings look like in both cases?

The problem is either:

The selector doesn't match the interface on the system unexpectedly
Basically the filter is used to match properties on the devices interfaces currently in KM PnP state. If an interface's properties match what is logically being requested in the selector, then it is added to the device information collection.

Answer (score 0):

What do the AQS selector strings look like in both cases?

The problem is either:

1. The selector doesn't match the interface on the system unexpectedly

Basically the filter is used to match properties on the devices interfaces currently in KM PnP state.  If an interface's properties match what is logically being requested in the selector, then it is added to the device information collection.

Maybe try FindAllAsync without a selector, then see what interfaces are currently being enumerated by KM PnP.  Request the properties that are in the selector.  Once you see the interface that you think you should be seeing, logically figure out why it is not matching with the selector.

2. The device is not paired.

If the device is not paired, then there won't be any devnodes or interfaces to represent it.  Hence it cannot be discovered by FindAllAsync

3. The device is paired, but does not have the profile you think it has.

The Bluetooth bus driver will only create PnP state for profiles it understands.  The PnP state is required for FindAllAsync to find it.  RFCOMM is a basic one, so it should work though.

Anyway, start with writing some test code as outlined in 1.  That will give you some infortmation to get further in your investigation.

Also, checkout the new Windows 10 API changes for Windows.Devices.Enumeration.  There are new ways to discover Bluetooth devices.

-Sam

Comment: Is this more helpful?  I would like to seem some more investigation though.